# SQL Only equal to day and month not year

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a database where users stores their birthday. y-m-d, and Im trying to get every user that has the same birthday. But the year can be difference between each user.

So how do I turn this: `SELECT username FROM table_name WHERE birthday='$birthday'` to a working script?

$birthday gets its data from a form, where the inputs is example: 2002-02-02. And if users have this birthday its echo it out. But the problem is that it checks with the year, and Im trying to only get month and day, not year.

I have tried with (EXACT(MONTH FROM ...) but didnt get it to work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do **something** like

```
SELECT username FROM table_name 
WHERE MONTH(birthday)=MONTH('$birthday') 
AND DAY(birthday)=DAY('$birthday')
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`MONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) and [`DAYOFMONTH()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth). For today's birthdays:

```
SELECT username 
FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
AND DAYOFMONTH(birthday) = DAYOFMONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

For a specific date (February 2nd):

```
SELECT username 
FROM table_name
WHERE MONTH(birthday) = 2
AND DAYOFMONTH(birthday) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but maybe I wasnt complete clear. Sorry about that. But I wanted to have something like what Egor answered

Comment: I thought the question was clear. Can you clarify what you;'re looking for?

Comment: The question was that I just wanted to get the month and day from my form where you ask a date and prints out every user. The form is just simple <input type="date" name="Birthday">.