# return a specific element between 2 dates using mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have some trouble with mysql,

I have in my database some horoscope signs stored with there dates (begin and end).

for example the aquarius is stored between 2001-01-20 and 2001-02-18.

all dates begin by 2000 (year), and when it comes to the next year it is 2001.

Now I have an user, that have a birthday date. I want to return his sign, so I tried to do a request,

for example if my user is born '1990-12-26', I juste want to compare the day and the month, so I did a request like that

```
$query = "SELECT  `zodiac_signs__id` ,  `zodiac_signs__name` ,  `zodiac_signs__img`,  
        RIGHT(  `zodiac_signs__date_start` , 5 ) as date_debut , 
        RIGHT( `zodiac_signs__date_end`,5)   as date_fin 
        FROM  `fit__zodiac_signs`  
        WHERE  '{$date_naissance}' BETWEEN RIGHT(  `zodiac_signs__date_start` , 5 ) 
            AND   RIGHT( `zodiac_signs__date_end`,5)";
```

What I do not understand is that, the request returns no results,

all users should have a sign returned.

I most probably did something wrong, with the manipulation of the dates, but I really do not know where.

Some suggest to store day, and month in two different columns, but the database have not been to store this informations in two different columns.

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If every sign is stored in the year 2001 then you can change in the query the date of birth to 2001 as well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345671/sql-only-equal-to-day-and-month-not-year

Comment: no, some signs are in 2000, but some others to 2001 because somes signs crushed the years

Comment: See in the link above the answer from nicolas. He uses day and month from the dates only.

Comment: the trouble is that it does not return what is expected

Answer (score 1):

If {$date_naissance} is in format '1990-12-26', then you might want to do:

```
 ... WHERE  '".substr($date_naissance,-5)."' BETWEEN RIGHT( ...
```

Comment: in fact, I transformed the date to an other `$date_naissance = date('m-d',  strtotime($naissance));` but it does not return anything expected

Comment: what sql type is "zodiac_signs__date_end" field ? Is a VARCHAR(10) OR a DATETIME ?

Comment: then, BETWEEN RIGHT(  `zodiac_signs__date_start` , 5 ) is returning the time (minutes:seconds) instead of the date...

Comment: i've tried also changin right by date_format `SELECT `zodiac_signs__id` , `zodiac_signs__name` , `zodiac_signs__img`, RIGHT( `zodiac_signs__date_start` , 5 ) , RIGHT( `zodiac_signs__date_end`,5) FROM `fit__zodiac_signs` WHERE  '12-26' BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT( `zodiac_signs__date_start` , '%m-%d' )  AND DATE_FORMAT( `zodiac_signs__date_end`,'%m-%d') ` but the result remain the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57898/discussion-between-lpg-and-stanislas-piotrowski).